# AmbiguousParameterSet in a function with multiple ParameterSetName

Tags: powershell, parameters, powershell-2.0

I'm writing a function to select files under a given path, based on conditions.

These are my input parameters:

- $Path:        mandatory, string
- $OwnedBy:     optional, string
- $NotOwnedBy:  optional, string
- $BiggerThan:  optional, int
- $SmallerThan: optional, int

I'd like to make my function accepts multiple filter-parameters but avoiding those conflicting, so that the function refuse $OwnedBy and $NotOwnedBy, or $BiggerThan and $SmallerThan together. The possible combinations should be:

1. My-Function -Path [string]
2. My-Function -Path [string] -OwnedBy [string]
3. My-Function -Path [string] -NotOwnedBy [string]
4. My-Function -Path [string] -BiggerThan [int]
5. My-Function -Path [string] -SmallerThan [int]
6. My-Function -Path [string] -OwnedBy [string] -BiggerThan [int]
7. My-Function -Path [string] -OwnedBy [string] -SmallerThan [int]
8. My-Function -Path [string] -NotOwnedBy [string] -BiggerThan [int]
9. My-Function -Path [string] -NotOwnedBy [string] -SmallerThan [int]

I'm using a ParameterNameSet for each of the above combination

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParametersetName="Set1")]
Param(
    [Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$true)]
    [String] $Path,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Set2")]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Set6")]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Set7")]
    [String] $OwnedBy,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Set3")]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Set8")]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Set9")]
    [String] $NotOwnedBy,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Set4")]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Set6")]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Set8")]
    [String] $BiggerThan,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Set5")]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Set7")]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Set9")]
    [String] $SmallerThan
)
```

but it works only if the call is done like at point 1.
All other ways give me an error like this:

```
My-Function : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At line:1 char:3
+ My-Function <<<<  aaa -OwnedBy sss
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [My-Function], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,My-Function
```

Comment: Do you really, really need parameter sets? Just make the path mandatory and leave the rest as optional. Maybe make the OwnedBy and NotOwnedBy into their own sets so that they are exclusive to eachother, but I don't really see a need for 9 parameter sets here.

Comment: You're getting this error, because the parameter sets 2-5 are subsets of the parameter sets 6-9. You may be able to get this to work with [dynamic parameter](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2014/05/29/dynamic-parameters-in-powershell/) sets (not sure about it, though), but I think the simplest solution would be to add some logic inside the script that makes each of the pairs `$OwnedBy`/`$NotOwnedBy` and `$BiggerThan`/`$SmallerThan` mutally exclusive.

Comment: Yes, i initially implemented the logic inside the function, i was just trying the ParameterSetName way for learning purpose. Anyway, i'm going to try with dynamic parameter, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As Ansgar said, you have overlapping subsets. The simplest way to fix it without re-thinking your strategy is to keep your current parameter sets and make all the parameters mandatory (this requires version 3.0+):

```
function Test {
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParametersetName="Set1")]
Param(
    [Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$true)]
    [String] $Path,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Set2",Mandatory=$true)]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Set6",Mandatory=$true)]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Set7",Mandatory=$true)]
    [String] $OwnedBy,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Set3",Mandatory=$true)]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Set8",Mandatory=$true)]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Set9",Mandatory=$true)]
    [String] $NotOwnedBy,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Set4",Mandatory=$true)]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Set6",Mandatory=$true)]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Set8",Mandatory=$true)]
    [String] $BiggerThan,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Set5",Mandatory=$true)]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Set7",Mandatory=$true)]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Set9",Mandatory=$true)]
    [String] $SmallerThan
)

}
```

You basically implemented optionality yourself by strictly defining the sets.

Comment: @LucaClavarino strange, I tested this before posting, with every combination. If you modified the code at all could you post that?

Comment: i copied your entire code, past it into a new powershell (version 2.0) window and run : Test "aaa" -OwnedBy "bbb". This is the result:Test : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At line:1 char:5
+ Test <<<<  "aaa" -OwnedBy "bbb"
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Test], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Test

Comment: @LucaClavarino I just tested it with a positional parameter (since I forgot to before) and it worked fine.. let me try 2.0.

Comment: @LucaClavarino yeah this is definitely an issue with 2.0. Works in 3.0+. I'm just not sure why yet,

Comment: curious. i'll give it a try on a powershell 3 as soon as i can, thanks again